# Get powers of a perfect power number

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, math

I have a problem which is to find the 2 powers of any number (numbers that don't have any powers such as 5 will return null), powers being and 2 integer numbers that when added power to return the said number. Here are some examples:

```
4 -> {2, 2}
5 -> null 
6 -> null
7 -> null
8 -> {2, 3}
10 -> null
etc...
```

Although my code below works, however its too slow, when passed through the problem (about 100 integer.max values) it takes over the set time (16 seconds), anything I could to optimize this code?

```
public static int[] isPerfectPower(int n) {  
    int limit = (int)Math.round((n/((double)5/2)));

    for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++) {  
        double result = Math.pow(n, (double)1/i);   
        result = (double)Math.round(result * Math.pow(10, 10)) /  Math.pow(10, 10);
        if((result == Math.floor(result))) return new int[] {(int)result, i};
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @backdoor thanks for responding, but can to elaborate on how this speeds up my code?

Comment: Your code is fine, but your `limit` is way too large. Given that `pow(2, 31) = 2147483648` exceeds the range of a Java `int`, there's no way that the exponent in your power can be larger than `30`, so you never need a `limit` larger than `30`. For smaller `n` you can get away with a smaller limit, but from a simplicity point of view it may be enough simply to hard-code a limit of `30` for all `n`. (If you want to get fancy, you could also test for powers of 2 to begin with, then the largest exponent you need to consider is `19`, since `pow(3, 20)` is again too large for a Java `int`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your input is no more than 2147483647, which means there are only so many possible answers. Here is an ordered list of all 108 perfect powers with a power of 5 or more.

```
2**5, 2**7, 3**5, 4**5, 2**11, 3**7, 5**5, 6**5, 2**13, 4**7, 7**5, 8**5, 9**5, 5**7, 10**5, 2**17, 11**5, 3**11, 12**5, 6**7, 13**5, 2**19, 14**5, 15**5, 7**7, 16**5, 17**5, 3**13, 18**5, 8**7, 19**5, 20**5, 21**5, 4**11, 9**7, 22**5, 23**5, 24**5, 2**23, 25**5, 10**7, 26**5, 27**5, 28**5, 11**7, 29**5, 30**5, 31**5, 32**5, 12**7, 33**5, 34**5, 5**11, 35**5, 36**5, 13**7, 4**13, 37**5, 38**5, 39**5, 40**5, 14**7, 41**5, 3**17, 42**5, 43**5, 44**5, 15**7, 45**5, 46**5, 47**5, 48**5, 16**7, 49**5, 50**5, 51**5, 6**11, 52**5, 17**7, 53**5, 54**5, 55**5, 2**29, 56**5, 57**5, 18**7, 58**5, 59**5, 60**5, 61**5, 19**7, 62**5, 63**5, 64**5, 65**5, 3**19, 5**13, 66**5, 20**7, 67**5, 68**5, 69**5, 70**5, 21**7, 71**5, 72**5, 7**11, 73**5
```

Therefore you only have to check for squares, cubes, and entrees of the list above.

A slightly more naïve method would be to check all ten powers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, and 29. You do not need to check any other powers, as they are either non-prime or too large to ever work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by factoring a number.

Lets `n = p1^k1 * p2^k2 * p3^k3` where p1,p2,p3 = prime number.

Then a number will be perfect power if `gcd(k1, k2, k3) != 1` (They need to have common divisor)..

Example:

```
2500 = 2^2 * 5^4
     = 2^2 * (5^2)^2
     = 2^2 * 25^2
     = 50^2
```

This way you can calculate power of perfect powers.

**Way 2:**

Lets `n = a^b` ... you need to find `a & b` where `b < log(n)`...

Now u need to find `a`.. you can find `a` using binary search. this complexity `log(a)`...to calculate a^b1..... u need log(n) operation.

So complexity for all binary operation: `(log(n) * log log(n))`

Total complexiy : `log(n) * (log(n) * log log(n))`

Comment: Factoring is slow. Just try all the possible roots; there are only log₂(n) of them.

Comment: there is many way to do it. if A <=10^8 then u can pre generate. otherwise u can factorize using pre generate prime number. or you can do it sqrt(A)..

Comment: Actually I realized you only have to check prime roots; there are only O(log n / log log n) of those; 11 in this case for 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mark Dickinson suggested, the most efficient change to my code ( without completely changing it ) would be to cap my limit at 30 instead of 2/3 of n, as any number >2 with a power greater then 30 would exceed the Integer.max limit, therefore but adding an extra expression ( i < 30 ) would immensely speed up the code, the code will be displayed below.

```
      public static int[] isPerfectPower(int n) {
        for(int i = 2; i <= ((n < 30) ? n : 30) && i < 30; i++) {
            double result = (double)Math.round(Math.pow(n, (double)1/i) * Math.pow(10, 10)) /  Math.pow(10, 10);
            if((result == Math.floor(result))) return new int[] {(int)result, i};
        }
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: The changes were all given by @Mark Dickinson, Thanks!